# java.sql.SQLException: No suitbale driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exambledb

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

I am Facing this issue form last 2 days.
I am getting this issue while i am connection servlet with JDBC (Servlet JDBC Integration).
I added jar files using build path. and also Web-app/lib folder.
Output getting Blank Screen.

Error: No suitable Driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exampledb.

Also tried by adding different versions for mysql-connection-j drivers.

Also tried, But getting same.
Error:  No suitable Driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhos/exampledb.
help out form this issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fg7mx.png)

I used Eclipse
I used Web project in eclipse
I wrote a program to retrieve a table data over servlet.
I am getting Blank Screen by passing above issue.
Please solve this issue.

Comment: [Please never post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.
There is also no code so you're unlikely to get any further help

Comment: As you seem to be using `DriverManager`, instead of a data source, and your driver is in the WAR, make sure you explicitly load the driver with `Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")` before trying to make a connection. Automatic driver loading doesn't work on Tomcat for drivers inside the WAR.